# Where can I go to play an acoustic piano regularly?

Tags: piano, practice

*I love my digital piano.  She's got weighted keys and can be quiet when she needs to, but for practice there are few things which compare to a real nice acoustic piano.*

I live in London so there must be some places to go every week or 2 for the real deal.  Bonus points for cheaper places, but I'm willing to accept that a Bosendorfer might push the price up!

So, the question is, Where might I be able to go to play a good quality acoustic piano regularly?

Comment: No idea on the accuracy or validity of this information, sorry: http://streetpianos.com/london2012/ It says some are still available.

Comment: Make it an answer man, let me give you rep :D There are indeed plenty of street pianos around.  Including one in Camden Market and Multiple at st Pancras Station

Comment: I live in Colorado, so this isn't much help to you (...now), but I'm planning to start a non-profit organization to provide access to practice rooms and pianos for people who don't have them at home.

Comment: @KyleStrand That's a great idea! I don't have a piano to play regularly, this would be of great help :) *bon courage*!

Comment: You could also contact ABRSM and ask if they can aid you. I'm not sure if they can but it does not take a lot to send an email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest schools, but more and more schools are getting rid of their pianos. However, if you find one, ask about seeing the caretaker and going in at holidays (now!) or weekends. Some pubs may provide, and maybe you could play in the background when punters are in. Occasionally rehearsal studios (not cheap) have a real piano.Colleges , especially music colleges, will have the facility - you either ask nicely, or walk in brazenly, it's up to you !

Alternatively, print some fliers, and go posting locally. There will be a neighbour, possibly an old biddy, who would love you to play the piano her kids learnt on 40 yrs ago !
Some churches will have retained their piano, or there may be one in the Church Hall that needs playing : always mention that acoustic pianos need regular playing !

Comment: Do you think ministers would be offended if I asked to play with their organ?

Comment: I'm only guessing, but it could depend on their persuasion. You'll find their organs have a very different action from their pianos, though.

Comment: i am PRETTY sure he was jokin'...

Comment: I think I've covered my back, so to speak...

Comment: Bravo on raising the tone Ti... wait...

Answer (score 3):

No idea on the accuracy or validity of this information, sorry: http://streetpianos.com/london2012 says some are still available.

Failing that, these look reasonably priced: http://www.jspianos.com/hire/practice-room-hire - I might use them myself next time I'm working in London, since real pianos kinda scare me.

Answer (score 2):

schools, churches, nursing homes.  that's probably about it.

nursing homes have sort of gone to digitals or else you may find their acoustic way out of tune.  but it's worth a shot.  you'll definitely have an appreciative audience.

other than that, pony up the cash and buy one, or make do with your digital.  My cp-33 is fine for me, at least.  I like to come across an acoustic, though.

Comment: The problem is not cost unfortunately, It's space.  London is not exactly known for spacious living conditions

Comment: True.  Same for me.  I could fit an upright in my microscopic living room, but, mmmm, if I'm going acoustic, it'll have to be a grand.

Comment: There's a business opportunity here, I'm sure of it!

Comment: It'll be like those driving days you can go on in a Ferrari

Comment: There are some quite small studio pianos available, a ship's piano is one that comes to mind, soundboard same height as the keys.With 88 notes, all are going to be as wide as each other though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of central practice rooms I've used:

http://www.jspianos.com/hire/practice-room-hire
http://themusicstudios.co.uk/rates.php

And a list from RAM (PDF):

http://www.ram.ac.uk/viewfile.cfm?id=794&h=C4EEABAD93A5D4D0B5D22A704D1F4E39F63F9CDC2DA53FE99DC276FCF6EF25DD

Typical prices are between £10 and £20 an hour.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth trying Lonely Pianos - They list pianos and rehearsal rooms that are available to hire. http://lonelypianos.com/